# Wordpress isleMag theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have a website www.gyoby.com which I already installed a new theme "Islemag" so I try to configure this theme to look like the demo, all it's OK but “Islemag powered by WordPress” still in the footer, please to help me removing this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Because this was a free theme, I downloaded it and did a little digging.  Here's what I found:

There are two ways to do this, depending on whether you have the theme saved to your computer.  If you do, do this:

Open the theme folder on your computer, and find the file called "footer.php"
Open it, and on lines 113 to 117, you'll see this code:

```
<?php printf(
    __( '%1$s powered by %2$s', 'islemag' ),
    sprintf( '<a href="https://themeisle.com/themes/islemag/" rel="nofollow">%s</a>', esc_html__( 'Islemag', 'islemag' ) ),
    sprintf( '<a href="http://wordpress.org/" rel="nofollow">%s</a>', esc_html__( 'WordPress', 'islemag' ) )
); ?>
```

Delete those lines, then save the file and reupload the theme to your site. (If you know how to create a child theme, then do that, and upload your new footer.php to the child theme folder, but if you don't, then ignore this.)

If you do not have the theme saved on your computer, then go to your dashboard and go to the Appearance menu, and click Editor.  This will bring up the files for your theme, as well as an editor.  Click your footer.php file on the right side of the screen, this will load the file into the editor.  Then, find the lines that I mentioned earlier, and delete them. Click the "Update File" button, and you're done.